# Current in a closed DC circuit

Tags: voltage, power, ohms-law

I am in the process of learning the fundamentals of electricity, however I am having trouble understanding why there is no measurable current in a closed DC circuit when there is no power consumption.

Joules law states that there would be no current if there is no power consumed by the circuit.

However if I connect the two terminals of a battery together with a simple wire then voltage will flow until the battery is dead. So if there is voltage flowing through the circuit why is there no current?

Comment: Your meter is broken or the fuse is blown or you didn't connect it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However if I connect the two terminals of a battery together with a simple wire then voltage will flow until the battery is dead. So if there is voltage flowing through the circuit why is there no current?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3qW44.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A battery model with its internal resistance and a short circuit.*

We don't say "there is voltage flowing in a circuit" in the same way we don't say there is pressure flowing in a pipe. There is voltage *across* the circuit and *current* flowing through the circuit.

If you short-circuit a battery current *will* flow. The amount of current will be limited by the internal resistance of the battery and this is why the battery will get hot.

You are correct that there will be no power consumption by the load but there will be power consumption by the battery itself and the evidence is the heat. For certain battery chemistries a short-circuit can induce fire or explosion.

> Ohm's law states that there would be no current if there is no power consumed by the circuit.

No. Ohm's law states the relationship between volts, amperes and resistance. There is no mention of power. It's Joule's law that relates power, voltage and current and it has various forms derived using Ohm's law: \$ P = VI = \frac {V^2}R = I^2 R \$. From this we can see that if V<sub>LOAD</sub> = 0 then P = 0 no matter how much current flows.

As I have shown, power *is* consumed by the circuit. It just happens to be all consumed in the battery.

---

It appears that your confusion is partially from experimental measurements. Shorting out a power source with an ammeter is generally a very bad idea and can be fatal. (Look up "arc flash" on YouTube for some horrendous examples.) You were fortunate that your meter was adequately fused. As described above, the current was only limited by the internal battery resistance and, in time, the fuse. Learn this lesson well and make it a habit to always move the meter lead back to the VΩmA socket and switch off or to V after taking a current reading
.

Comment: My mistake. You are correct. It’s joules law, not ohms. I changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: Good. See the update.

Answer (score 3):

> However if I connect the two terminals of a battery together with a simple wire then voltage will flow until the battery is dead. So if there is voltage flowing through the circuit why is there no current?

Current will flow in this scenario. Who told you it won't?

Voltage doesn't flow in this circuit or any other.

As an analogy, say we have a river whose current flows from a high altitude to a low altitude. Altitude is analogous to voltage in this situation as it determines how quickly the river current flows. But the altitude doesn't flow in the river.

> there is no measurable current in a closed DC circuit when there is no power consumption.

This isn't a general rule for all circuits. If a wire has very low (approximately zero) resistance, then current can flow through it with approximately zero power consumption.

Only in circuits with non-zero resistance would it be true.

Comment: I expected current to flow, but when try to measure it my multimeter does not register any current. I guess that there is just not enough current for the multimeter to pick up then.

Comment: @McWayWeb The fuse in your meter is probably blown. Happens to the best of us. You should have stated in your original question that your multimeter didn't register anything.

Comment: I don’t think that it’s a fuse issue, because there is no fuse inside and the documentation states that it uses unfused shunts. However the 10A rating measures current down to 10mA but nothing registers. The next setting down is 200mA which beeps and registers nothing. This is supposed to signify that the measurement is too high for the setting being used. Is it my multimeter that is malfunctioning?

Comment: Can you share a photo of how you connected the meter?